# How to show menu from left on image click in windows Universal apps?

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I am currently working on Windows Universal Apps.In that there is requirement to show menu from left side when User clicks on menu icon. I want add a ListView inside it and handle the selectionchanged event based on user's selected item. Now, the problem with Flyout is that it opens like a popup on clicking the icon but what I actually want to do is *it should come from left side of the window* .For e.g in Gmail application of android. Please can anyone suggest how to achieve this. Please find below my code which I added in Flyout below:

```
<Image Source="ms-appx:///Images/menu_image.png"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       Tapped="Image_Tapped"
                       Width="60"
                       Height="90"
                       Grid.Column="0"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                        <Flyout>
                            <Grid x:Name="SettingsPane"
              Background="{StaticResource AppBackGroundColor}"
              Grid.Row="0"
              Width="380">
                                <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
                                    <TransitionCollection>
                                        <EdgeUIThemeTransition/>
                                    </TransitionCollection>
                                </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"
                       Margin="8">
                                    <TextBlock Name="SidebarTitletxtblk"
                           FontSize="25"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                           Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                                <ListView Grid.Row="1"
                     x:Name="LocationPickerList"
                     SelectionChanged="LocationPickTypeSelected"
                     Margin="0,10,0,0"
                     ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GenericListViewContainerStyle}"
                     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LocationPickerListItemTemplate}"></ListView>
                            </Grid>
                        </Flyout>
                    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                </Image>
```

Comment: Can some one help me on this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't override the Flyout's standard transition. If you want to apply something else then you can use a Popup instead and customize it however you'd like. To have it slide in from the left apply an EdgeUIThemeTransition (if it's short) or a PaneThemeTransition (if it's full height) with Edge=Left.

For example:

```
<Popup x:Name="flyoutPane" IsOpen="False" IsLightDismissEnabled="True" 
     Width="320" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <Popup.ChildTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <!--<EdgeUIThemeTransition Edge="Left" />-->
            <PaneThemeTransition Edge="Left" />
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Popup.ChildTransitions>
    <Grid Width="380" Height="{Binding ElementName=flyoutPane, Path=Height}"  Background="{ThemeResource FlyoutBackgroundThemeBrush}" >
        <TextBlock Text="Grid contents here" />
    </Grid>
</Popup>
```

And trigger it from your Button Click (your Image sounds like it should be a Button rather than using Tap, unless you have an alternate keyboard method - you can template off the button look while keeping the button semantics).

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Height is only important if we want the Popup sized to the screen
    flyoutPane.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
    flyoutPane.IsOpen = true;
}
```

If you're doing many of these you can create a custom control with an attached property similar to FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout.

Comment: Thanks Rob. It worked as expected. Can we handle its transition speed. When I click on Image the menu opened very fast.

Comment: No, it's a standard transition. If you want something custom you'll can define your own animation and apply it, but I'd recommend staying with the system transitions.